# Customize columns and multiple field sort in laravel table listing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have laravel project where the users are listed along with related attributes like email,phone etc in the admin. I want to give an option for the admin to customize the columns in the listing.(like this https://youtu.be/lKnMPYtQg_c) There are 14 attributes from which the user can choose the columns. What is the best possible way to implement this using laravel Eloquent?

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
 public function locations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Location', 'user_locations', 'usersId', 'locationId');
    }
    public function interests()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Interest', 'user_interests', 'usersId', 'interestId');
    }
    }
```

Also some of the columns needs to have multiple sort option , like sort name first then sort that result according to age.

Is there any package available which handle this kind of situation ? or is there any sample code which I can refer ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom filterable trait. [Here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-create-a-laravel-restful-api-allowing-requests-with-url-params?page=1) is one example of such trait, although it was not design specifically for what you are asking.

You can use it in combination with [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to load the selected relationship and to sort according to the filterable fields.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the 100% solution to your problem but, I know a popular package named - [Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/), which can help you to transform your data according to the client requests.

You can use this package to handle your different situations. Hope this will help you!